# What criteria make for good Mii coaches on Champion's Road?

Tags: nintendo-wii, pro-evolution-soccer-2010

In PES 2010 on the Wii, you can train Miis for your team. In doing so, you choose 2 players from your team as coaches and once chosen you are given a "compatibility rating" out of 3. What do you need to look for to get the highest compatibility?

Whatever combination I try I've never had a rating above 2 and that was with 2 goalkeepers. With outfield players, I've not had above 1 - and it's not like I haven't got good players (Rooney, Messi etc).